# Is there an article that discusses the influence of Robert Heinlein on John Varley?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, influences, john-varley

I just finished rereading *Red Thunder* by John Varley, which is a fine read, as are the other two books in his trilogy.  This time, Heinlein's *Rocket Ship Galileo* flashed into my brain.

Please note, I am **NOT** in any way suggesting that Varley in any way copied Heinlein.  Varley's book is
richer in many ways than Heinlein's, which is a book for young readers.  I read it when I was 13. It was the first science fiction I ever read.

Nevertheless, Varley and Heinlein are linked together on many inside-cover blurbs, e.g.,

> Varley has earned the mantle of Heinlein

Can anyone recommend an article which discussses the influence of Heinlein on Varley?

Comment: I can't point to any article, but Heinlein's influence on Varley is unmistakable. In his novels *Steel Beach* and *The Golden Globe*, he even references Heinlein with a subculture called "Heinleiners". And in *Rolling Thunder* which is dedicated to Heinlein), the main character is named Podkayne after Heinlein's titular character in his novel *Podkayne of Mars*.

Comment: The question should be left open because it has a definite answer. In this case, the answer is evidently No. If the answer had been Yes, with a citation, then would there still be a call to close the question?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Well, there's no way to tell. If someone wanted to spend weeks down the rabbit hole of the fanzine archive, they might come across something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have John Varley's own words, in a blog he wrote after accepting the 2009 Robert A. Heinlein award:

> I’ve won Hugo and Nebula awards, but none of them mean as much to me as this one does. I remember Mr. Green, the librarian at C.O. Wilson Junior High, handing me a copy of RED PLANET, by Heinlein, and saying I might enjoy it. Enjoy it? I went NUTS! I read ALL Heinlein’s books in the coming weeks, and all the other science fiction I could find. That book set the course of my life...

Source: https://varley.net/nonfiction/news/the-2009-robert-a-heinlein-award/

Comment: Looks like you spent only one hour down the rabbit hole!  Thanks.

Comment: @ab2 I chased a different rabbit.